# Apply conditional formatting rules to Google spreadsheet column past set limit (10)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Limit to conditional formatting appears to be 10 per column. Any work around except creating another column next to it for those additional rules or functions, then copy/paste data from one column to next?

[Conditional formatting limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ExQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google App scripts to write your own set of rules since the default is limited to 10 per column. The below links should help:

- Google Help: [Apply conditional formatting rules](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413)
- [How to condition a cell, so that if the value of a cell is higher than a certain number, it will automatically show a certain number or else show that value.](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-condition-cell-so-that-if-value.html)